# Add ImageView to a ListActivity

Tags: android, listview, layout, listactivity

I would like to add an `ImageView` under my `ListView` in my `ListActivity`.  So that when the user scrolls to the end of the list, the `ImageView` shows.

I can't seem to get my layout correct.  Either the `ImageView` is not displayed at all, or if I use layout_weights, then both the `ListView` and `ImageView` get 50% of the screen.  Any ideas how I can get what I want?  Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/> 

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/android:empty"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/list_no_items" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/instruct_image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/instructions"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I don't think what you want to accomplish is easily done with standard Android layouts. You can't have a `ListView` within another `ScrollView`.

You could use the `ListView` footer to position the `ImageView` below the ListView.

Or, you could try to add the `ImageView` as the last row in the ListView.  To do this, override the `getView` method of the adapter and return the `ImageView` if it is the last row.

Comment: I can't use a footer since the ImageView is large enough to fill the whole screen.  I'll try the getView method, although I'm not really sure how to do that.  It should be possible since I added the image successfully to each listview item which gave me what I want (except for the fact the image showed up 10 times).

Comment: Well, you can configure the ImageView to not take up the whole screen.  But if you don't want it always visible, that doesn't make sense.  In the ListView approach I would add a dummy element at the end of your adapter, then in getView you have a check `if(isDummyElement()) showImage() else showNormalListView()`.  Its still a bit of a hack, but I can't think of a cleaner way.

Comment: Well, after a lot of work I managed to use `getView` to get this to work.  It sort of seems like a hack, but it does exactly what I want.  Thanks.